# Way to manually lower an object layer in JavaFX controller?

Tags: javafx

Im attempting to create a game, and I need some pieces of a Grid Pane to have click events, and for some to not. The way I have done this is with manually adding panes to the main Grid Pane as click events. But these also cover some of my other click events. I have a seperate function named "ObjClicked" which is triggered when an ImageView is clicked. I would like the ImageView to be a layer above the Pane Click events.

```
}
```

I have tried moving the ImageView to the top in SceneBuilder, but to no avail.

```
   for (int i = 0 ; i < numCols ; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < numRows; j++) {
                addPane(i, j);
            }
        }
    }


    private void addPane(int colIndex, int rowIndex) {
        Pane pane = new Pane();
        pane.setOnMouseEntered(e -> {
            System.out.printf("Mouse enetered cell [%d, %d]%n", colIndex, rowIndex);
        });
        grid.add(pane, colIndex, rowIndex);
    }
```

This covers all "cells" of the grid pane including the ImageView. I expect the imageview to still be clickable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I have tried moving the ImageView to the top in SceneBuilder

This is the wrong direction. The bottom-most child (the one with the highest index in the list of children) is drawn on top of other children. Furthermore since those children are added when loading the fxml, i.e. before the `for` loop is executed, the `GridPane.add` method adds new elements on top of the existing ones.

One way of fixing this issue is adding the `Pane`s at the beginning of the child list. Note that for large `numCols * numRows` you should rewrite this to use the `addAll` method for bulk insertion of nodes, since adding nodes to the front of a `ArrayList` (the backing list of the child list) has a suboptimal performance when done repeatedly. Probably you won't see a difference though.

```
private void addPane(int colIndex, int rowIndex) {
    Pane pane = new Pane();

    GridPane.setRowIndex(pane, rowIndex);
    GridPane.setColumnIndex(pane, colIndex);

    pane.setOnMouseEntered(e -> {
        System.out.printf("Mouse enetered cell [%d, %d]%n", colIndex, rowIndex);
    });

    grid.getChildren().add(0, pane); // add pane to front of child list
}
```